# Abstract classes and virtual methods: cannot access certain variables

Tags: c#

I am working with abstract classes and virtual methods. Currently I have a window form composed of a button click and two multiline textboxes where I am displaying the results. The base class has a default constructor and a constructor that accepts all the necessary data the base needs. There are two classes `Trees` and `Tomatoes` that have a default constructor and a constructor that is passed all the data.  I am able to display in textBox1 the item `name`, `number in stock` and `price`.

However I am not able to call and display for `Trees` the height variable named `tree_height` and the `Tomatoes` size and tomatoes per plat variables named `tomatoes_perplat` and `tomatoes_size`. It gives me the error does not contain a definition for those variables. How can I fix that?

**CODE**

```
namespace plant_shop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public abstract class Plants
        {
            public string the_name;
            public double num_stock;
            public double price_peritem;
            public double total_item_value;

            public Plants(string new_name, int new_stock, double new_price)
            {
                the_name = new_name;
                num_stock = new_stock;
                price_peritem = new_price;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "";
            }

            public virtual double Get_Value()
            {
                double s = 0;
                return s;
            }


        }

        public class Trees : Plants
        {
            double tree_height;
            public Trees(string new_name, int new_stock, double new_price, double new_height)
                : base(new_name, new_stock, new_price)
            {
                tree_height = new_height;
                total_item_value = num_stock * price_peritem;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                string s = "Tree" + "     " + num_stock + "      " +  the_name + "     " + price_peritem + "    " + tree_height ;
                return s;
            }

            public override double Get_Value()
            {
                total_item_value = num_stock * price_peritem;
                return total_item_value;
            }

        }

        public class Tomatoes : Plants
        {

            string sizeoftomato;
            int tomatoesinpat;

            public Tomatoes(string new_name, int new_stock, double new_price, int tomatoes_perplat, string tomatoes_size)
                : base(new_name, new_stock, new_price)
            {
                tomatoesinpat = tomatoes_perplat;
                sizeoftomato = tomatoes_size;  
                total_item_value = num_stock * price_peritem; 
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                string s = "Tomatoes" + "     " + num_stock + "      " + the_name + "     " + price_peritem;
                return s;
            }

            public override double Get_Value()
            {

                total_item_value = num_stock * price_peritem;
                return total_item_value;
            }
        }



        public void Report()
        {

             Trees trees1 = new Trees("Oak", 3, 14.40, 2);
             const string format = "{0,-26} {1,-25} {2,-25} {3,-25}";
             string trees1_result = String.Format(format, "Tree", trees1.the_name, trees1.num_stock, trees1.price_peritem, trees1.tree_height); //not showing `tree_height`            
             textBox1.AppendText(trees1_result + Environment.NewLine);
             textBox2.AppendText(trees1.Get_Value() + Environment.NewLine);            

             Tomatoes tomatoes1 = new Tomatoes("Big Boy", 30, 10, 12, "Large");
             const string format2 = "{0,-26} {1,-25} {2,-25} {3,-25}";
             string tomatoes1_result = String.Format(format2, "Tomatoe", tomatoes1.the_name, tomatoes1.num_stock, tomatoes1.price_peritem, tomatoes1.tomatoes_perplat, tomatoes1.tomatoes_size); //not showing `tomatoes_perplat` or `tomatoes_size`
             textBox1.AppendText(tomatoes1_result + Environment.NewLine);
             textBox2.AppendText(tomatoes1.Get_Value() + Environment.NewLine);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Report();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It would have really helped if: 1) You'd followed .NET naming conventions; 2) You'd created a short but *complete* program, ready to try to compile. 3) You'd not used nested classes, which complicate things needlessly. 4) You'd created a console app rather than a GUI (much simpler, and can easily show language questions 5) You'd said where the error was. I'll take a look anyway, but you could have helped us to help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now I've got the code somewhat compiling, it's clearer...

You can't access `trees1.tree_height` because it's private within the `Trees` class, and you're trying to access it from a method in the `Form1` class.

You can't access `tomatos_perplat` from the method because there's no such variable in the `Tomatoes` class - there's `tomatoesinpat`, but that's private too.

Ditto `tomatoes_size` - the field is called `sizeoftomato`, and is private.

Keeping your fields private is a *good* idea - I don't recommend making them public. Instead, you should expose [*properties*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) to expose data between classes. You can use [automatically implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) as an easy way to implement very simple properties.

I'd *strongly* encourage you to work on your organization though:

- Don't use nested classes for everything; they're handy occasionally, but it's usually better to have separate top-level classes
- Read the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045.aspx) and follow them
- Think about what your methods are trying to achieve - things like your `Get_Value` method are pointless at the moment
- I would *urge* you to experiment with console applications. They're less "exciting" than GUIs, but are *much* simpler to understand and experiment with.

Comment: +1 Perfect Explanation. Can you show me how to expose properties to expose data between classes with my example program?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) within your classes that have no [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) specified. By default, these fields will be private.

You should use [public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to expose these fields. You should also consider [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it:

```
public string sizeoftomato;             
public int tomatoesinpat;
```

These fields are *private* by default.

Note that fields are not usually appropriate for what you're doing. You really want properties:

```
public string SizeOfTomato { get; set; }
public int TomatoesInPlant { get; set; }
```